# Basic click function into AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm looking to convert a basic click function into an AJAX call, but I am not sure how to do so with appended responses I have that are sent from my php script.

How could I do this?

I have the following script now...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#admin_submit').click(function(){

        $.post("admin_help_send.php", $("#admin_help_form").serialize(),  function(response) {
            if (response == 'Your email was sent!') {
                $('#contactMessageStatus').append(response);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactSuccess");
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
                }, 2000);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').delay(5500).fadeOut(400);
            }
            else {
                $('#contactMessageStatus').append(response);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactFail");
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
                }, 2000);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').delay(5500).fadeOut(400);
            }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

It gets this response from php and apends the response..

```
if (!empty($email)) { 
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 

    //Should also do a check on the mail function
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
    } else {
        echo "Mail could not be sent!"; // failed message
    }

  } else { 
        //Invalid email
        echo "Invalid Email, please provide a valid email address.";
    }

} else {
    echo "Email Address was not filled out.";
}
```

Comment: im not sure what you are trying to ask, can you elaborate?

Comment: I want to be able to change that script to php and still be able to send back my echo's from php with the class I have assigned to it

Comment: change what script to php?

Comment: I'm sorry, change the javascript to AJAX**

Comment: `$.post` is an AJAX request. What do you mean?

Comment: I thought you needed something like this? `$.ajax({ 
      url: "file.php", 
      type: "POST",
      data: {
                 },`

Comment: not necessarily. is the code giving you problems? you would use `$.ajax` if you need to send extra parameters/options, but using `$.post` should work. Is the code not working?

Comment: No it is working. I just didn't think that it was AJAX. Extra parameters as in what?

Comment: this should tell you all the extra parameters/options you can use using `$.ajax` that you cant do with `$.post` : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: So, that is the only different between $.post and $.ajax? Just extra parameters?

Comment: as far as i know they both send `xhr` requests

Comment: Gotcha. I thought wrong then. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the different settings you can use with [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). This should get you where you need to be:

```
$('#admin_submit').click(function () {
    var sendData = $("#admin_help_form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "admin_help_send.php",
        data: sendData,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == 'Your email was sent!') {
                $('#contactMessageStatus').append(response);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactSuccess");
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
                }, 2000);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').delay(5500).fadeOut(400);
            } else {
                $('#contactMessageStatus').append(response);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactFail");
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
                }, 2000);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').delay(5500).fadeOut(400);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // handel errors here
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```